# PHP Database Connection - Calling Multiple Times

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following code to connect to my Database - PHP7 to MySQL

```
<?php


?>
```

The connection works fine.

My question is I'm calling this code around 5 times for each page request. This is because its included different functions.

Does this mean I'm making 5 DB connects for each page request? Or is it persistent and only called once?

If it is calling multiples times I could use a global to keep it to once.

thanks

Comment: it should be connecting once - however you are making multiple dispatches.

Comment: if you do 5 ```new database();``` in your code the connection is created 5 times, if you show us where and how you invoke the ```database``` class, we can help you more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using object, which creates connection in constructor. You will have as many connections as instances of `database` will be created.

1. If you create `database` instance, set it to some variable and use connection from this instance - there will be only one connection.
2. If you are creating `database` instance for each query - there will be many connections.